# if single-character filename exists within a string enclosed in [ ] entire string gets replaced with the character

Tags: bash, sh, csh

I was making a one-time script, calling it just a, and I got a very surprising error; the script contained some ipv6-adresses in square brackets, one including the letter a.

I got a message saying a was not a valid ipv6 address. So I experimented, and I think I found a very obscure bug. Or square brackets have another meaning than I think.

Try this code, in bash, sh or csh

```
mkdir /tmp/temp123
cd /tmp/temp123
echo [123abc]
touch a
echo [123abc]
```

The output is

```
[123abc]
a
```

My conclusion is:

- IF a file with a single-character filename exists in current directory
- AND that character is anywhere between [ ]
- AND there is whitespace outside [ ]   ( x[abc]y doesn't work )

then the shell replaces the entire substring, including the [ ].

Two-(or more?)-character filenames are not affecting this.

*WTF?!?*

Comment: The white space is not a requirement. for instance, if there is a file named `xby`, then `x[abc]y` would expand to this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug.

Characters in square brackets is the part of [glob matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Try:

```
cd /
echo [abcd]*
```

And if there is no files matched to the given mask then the mask printed as is.

So you need to quote your values:

```
mkdir /tmp/temp123
cd /tmp/temp123
echo "[123abc]"
touch a
echo "[123abc]"
```

Comment: Darn. In this case the solution was just to omit the [ ], they weren't needed for ipset. Second: Don't have one-character files lying around, use meaningful names ;-)

Comment: @LeifNeland One-character filenames aren’t the problem. Unquoted wildcards are the problem, one-character filenames just expose the problem (in this case).